# How can I pass values from an Outlook VBA form to an asmx web service?

Tags: vba, outlook, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to pass textbox values from an Outlook userform to an asmx web service.  I've done this successfully with PHP but now need to do so with VBA.  Currently the form does absolutely nothing on submit.  I believe something is wrong with what or how I'm passing to the send method.  Any suggestions how I can get this to work?

```
CliAcctNo = TicketCreateForm1.CliAcctNo.Value
ContactName = TicketCreateForm1.ContactName.Value
ContactNum = TicketCreateForm1.ContactNum.Value
Ext = TicketCreateForm1.Ext.Value
Email = TicketCreateForm1.Email.Value
TicketTitle = TicketCreateForm1.TicketTitle.Value
TicketDesc = TicketCreateForm1.Desc.Value

'DataToPost = ("cliacctno=44121&pname=John&pnum=404-223-9655&ext=0&emailaddress=john@noemail.com&tickettitle=test from vab&ticketdetails=test line item vba")
'objEvn.Parameters.Create "Test", "Test"
DataToPost = ("CliAcctNo&ContactName&ContactNum&Ext&Email&TicketTitle&TicketDesc")




Set objHttp = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
'Set objHttp = New MSXML2.XMLHTTPRequest
objHttp.Open "POST", "http://localhost/test/test.asmx"
objHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
'objHttp.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", "CreateTicket"
objHttp.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", "tempri.org/CreateTicket"
objHttp.Send (DataToPost)
```

Comment: `DataToPost` is always the same fixed string: did you mean to concatenate the variables obtained from your form into that string?

Comment: No I'm definitely not meaning to do that.  Each variable represents a param that needs sent to the web service.  How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

In your posted code you're sending a fixed string to the web service: you need to somehow include your parameters in that  -

```
CliAcctNo = TicketCreateForm1.CliAcctNo.Value
ContactName = TicketCreateForm1.ContactName.Value
ContactNum = TicketCreateForm1.ContactNum.Value
Ext = TicketCreateForm1.Ext.Value
Email = TicketCreateForm1.Email.Value
TicketTitle = TicketCreateForm1.TicketTitle.Value
TicketDesc = TicketCreateForm1.Desc.Value

'DataToPost = ("cliacctno=44121&pname=John&pnum=404-223-9655&ext=0&emailaddress=john@noemail.com&tickettitle=test from vab&ticketdetails=test line item vba")


 DataToPost = "cliacctno=" & CliAcctNo & _
             "pname=" & ContactName & _
             "pnum=" & ContactNum & _
             "ext=" & Ext & _
             "emailaddress=" & Email & _
             "tickettitle=" & TicketTitle & _
             "ticketdetails=" & TicketDesc
```

Comment: How would I go about passing those variables in the same string as the URL I'm calling? Currently I have this which I can see in Fiddler is returning hte value I've assigned to the variable but I can't figure out the syntax to add more than just the first one. `code` DataToPost = "http://localhost/SV2MVC/SV2MVC.asmx/CreateTicket?clientID=" + FclientID`code`

Comment: You're using POST, so data isn't supposed to be passed in the querystring - it goes in the request body.

Comment: Thanks.  I was able to get this working today by reverting back to my original approach and your reply posted above.  When that wasn't working initially I started taking different paths, including trying to send the query string, which I know now you cannot do except for GET.  Appreciate your replies on this.